# Dependent probability of r favorable over n trials

Tags: probability

```
P = sPn / oPn
where nPr, the number of permutations = n! / (n-r)!
```

I have determined that you can use the above formula to compute the probability `P` under the following circumstances:

- there are a fixed number of dependent trials, `n`
- we want `n` favorable outcomes (i.e. we want the outcome of all trials to be favorable)
- probability of each trial being favorable is `s / o`, where there are `o` possible outcomes and `s` of them are favorable, however once an outcome occurs it is removed from the possible outcomes in the next trial (non-replenishing), and thus the trials are dependent

However, what if we want `r` favorable outcomes, where `r <= n`, how would the formula be changed? It seems like one of the following formulas might be correct, and I'd like a confirmation if so, or perhaps it is a different formula altogether.

- `P = sPr / oPn` (my first guess)
- `P = (sPr * sP(n-r)) / oPn` (something in my brain is telling me this could be it as well)

Comment: `o / s, where there are o possible outcomes and s of them are favorable` In this case the fraction is greater than 1.

Comment: @callculus sorry that's a typo, I meant `s / o`, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @callculus I already did

Comment: I haven´t seen it.

Comment: @callculus Have you refreshed the page?

Comment: Yes and I had seen it.